# Java ProcessBuilder: curl: (1) Protocol "'https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Tags: java, curl, https, libcurl

I'm trying to call a cUrl command within Java to an https url.

I'm simply using the following:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("curl", "-X", "GET", "https://...");
Process p = pb.start();
```

The errorStream prints the following:

```
curl: (1) Protocol "'https" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

But if I execute the cUrl command in the terminal, it answers without any problem.

I also tried the following:

```
pb = new ProcessBuilder("curl", "-V");
```

which returns:

```
curl 7.54.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin16.0) libcurl/7.54.0 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.8
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz UnixSockets
```

I don't understand why the command works in the terminal, but not in Java context.

Comment: Try with `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/curl", "-X", "GET", "https://www.google.com");`, I have the same curl version on a Mac here and it worked correctly. Maybe there are two different curl's installed on your system.

Comment: Thanks for the suggest. The result with "curl" and "/usr/bin/curl" is the same, but I've found the cause: I had the url within ' symbols!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the cause.

I've noticed that my original command had apexes in the url argument, like this:

```
pb = new ProcessBuilder("curl", "-X", "GET", "'https://www.google.com'");
```

The apex cause the error above.

The solution is removing any apex in each argument, and it works perfectly.